# Specialised RegEx not working in Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to match certain numbers from the page and the regex I created is `/^(0 ?){1}([1-8] ?){1}(\d ?){9}$/` and it works fine in online regex tester tool. However, when I put it in my javascript function for some reason the regex matching with `^` & `$` is not working in my code.

```
var regex = /^(0 ?){1}([1-8] ?){1}(\d ?){9}$/; 
var text = $("body:first").html();
text = text.replace(regex, "<a href=\"tel:$&\">$&</a>");

$("body:first").html(text);
```

[Example at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PShYy/50/)

Comment: Do you understand *why* pasting an URL wasn't possible ? Because a question should be self sufficient, the fiddle should be a complement, not replace the relevant code.

Comment: BTW it's very hard to get what your question is, apart that it "is not working".

Comment: Sorry I din't knew that I had to paste the code in...I am new to this site.....I'll try to explain the question again

Comment: Because `.html()` returns the html tags and not just the inner text and you have RegEx start and end of string anchors, so nothing will ever match. Try using `$.trim($("body:first").text())` or remove the anchors altogether.

Comment: P.S. `(0 ?){1}` is the same as `(0 ?)`.  The `{1}` is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use the regular expression in `replace`, the start and end markers make no sense. Because you don't try to replace the whole string (which is the content of the `body`).

Change

```
var regex = /^(0 ?){1}([1-8] ?){1}(\d ?){9}$/;
```

to

```
var regex = /(0 ?){1}([1-8] ?){1}(\d ?){9}/;
```

(or `/(0 ?)([1-8] ?)(\d ?){9}/`)

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ELXFm/)

If you wanted to ensure you changed a whole cell, you could have looked for `>` and `<` but the cleanest solution would have been this :

```
var regex = /^(0 ?)([1-8] ?)(\d ?){9}$/; 
$('td').html(function(_,h){
    return h.replace(regex, "<a href=\"tel:$&\">$&</a>");
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/BE565/)

Comment: Basically what I want to do is look for phone number on page eg. 08457404400 and then hyperlink it. Hence according to the requirement criteria I created the regex. However if I dont put ^ and $ on regex it matches any numbers even though the number is hort in length

Comment: the above will only work on the cell I need to read entire DOM and find out the matching number

Comment: This operates on *all* cells. If you want it to check other types of elements, just enrich the selector.